# Locate and remove audio device kext (Virtual DJ)

Tags: macos, audio, kext

I try to uninstall VirtualDJ software from a macbook pro running El Capitan, following instructions delivered by both official site and users forums ->

- delete app in application folder
- delete preferences file : Users/me/Library/Preferences/com.atomixproductions.virtualdj.plist
- delete kext file : Users/me/Library/Extensions/com.atomixproductions.virtualdj.kext
- delete virtualdj folder located in documents folder and in Users/me/Library/

All of that seems very easy to do, but I still have "VirtualDJ Advanced Audio" device that still appears in my list of output devices :/

I have searched over all my system folders for a kext extension to manually remove, but nothing founded :(

Is there any way to locate it ?

Comment: Hi naja. Please note that we try to answer *the question that is asked*. It seems like you are more interested in *how to remove the device* rather than how to locate a kext relating to it. If that is the case, I would encourage you to [edit] your question to make this specific.

Comment: Thx for advice Michael ;) title has been changed, and "kext" tag has been added ...